# Making a font awesome play-circle icon spin for some seconds and load up a modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to incorporate a special  feature on my website,A font awesome play-circle icon that spins for some seconds onclick,then loads up a modal containing youtube iframe.

P.S i want just the circle ⭕️ part of the font awesome play-cirle icon to spin for se seconds when clicked on

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How can it be done?

Comment: Welcome to SO! As a new user, I recommend you review [ask] for tips on asking questions in a way that best enable the community to assist you. Can you update your post to clarify a specific question that you have? Even better, can you provide some code in an [mcve] snippet showing what you have tried, what the expected/desired behavior is and what the _actual_ behavior is? Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: To further clarify, it is unclear if you are seeking changing the rotation rate of the spinning circle, or have it shown only for a certain amount of time.  Either way, providing an [mcve] snippet will be extremely helpful for anyone looking to give you assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the font awesome circle spin by adding the fa-spin or fa-pulse class to it when it is clicked. You can then wait 5 seconds using the setTimeout function, and then open up the iframe and remove the fa-spin/pulse class to stop the spinning.

Here is an example:

**HTML:**

```
<i class="fas fa-spinner" onclick="openVideo(this)"></i>
```

You can replace fa-spinner with whatever font awesome icon you are using.

**Javascript:**

```
var isClicked = false //isClicked is here to prevent the user from triggering the function more that once
function openVideo(element) {
if (isClicked===false) {
  isClicked = true
  element.classList.add("fa-spin"); //Add class that makes it spin
  setTimeout(function() { //Wait 5 seconds
    //Code to open the youtube video goes here
    element.classList.remove("fa-spin") //Remove the class that makes it spin
    isClicked = false
  }, 5000)
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks Sir but it didnt really work...Are you on any social media platform? So i can send you a short clip of what i mean.

Comment: I was given a project to clone a website in school,i’m hooked at that part for days now